# Elements in <li> in contenteditable sometimes don't receive keypress event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contenteditable

I created a `contenteditable` `div`. I want to lock text editing (in the example below, I want to lock "yes") within one of the children. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="foo" contenteditable="true">this is a test
    <div contenteditable="false"> 
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="test" contenteditable="true" href="stackoverflow.com">a link here</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    yes
    </div>
    ...    
</div>
```

and JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    alert("div " + e.which);
});

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    alert("a " + e.which);
});
```

Link to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wCs8J/1/

The problem is, when you click on the right side of `<li>` (when the cursor is default arrow), you'll be able to edit text in `<a>`. However, `<a>` doesn't receive `keypress`, only main `div` receives it. Why? And what should I do to make it working?

Comment: maybe you shouldn't have nested content editable areas?

Comment: without them, <a> tag won't ever receive any event.

Comment: aurora 24, probably earlier versions also.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the ContentEditable off the `#foo` continued to broadcast events from `#test` just fine

http://jsfiddle.net/Maslow/wCs8J/2/

Perhaps it's a browser specific problem?

Comment: but #foo **must** be contenteditable. It's the main div of wysiwyg editor.